# Why is my onClick fired on component rendering?

Tags: reactjs

In the following code (extract of complete code), the button onClick of ContextHookInfo component is fired directly when I refresh the page, and I don't have a clue why. Anyone has got an idea please?

```
const UseContextTheme = {
    light: {
        name: 'light',
        style: {
            color: "#0f0",
            backgroundColor: "#fff"
        }
    },
    dark: {
        name: 'dark',
        style: {
            color: "#fff",
            backgroundColor: "#0f0"
        }
    }
}

const HookContext = React.createContext({ selectedTheme: UseContextTheme.light, themeSetter: () => {} });

function App() {
    const [useContextSelectedTheme, useContextThemeSetter] = useState(UseContextTheme.dark);
    return (
        <HookContext.Provider value={{ selectedTheme: useContextSelectedTheme, themeSetter: useContextThemeSetter}}>
            <ContextHookTest>
                <ContextHookInfo />
            </ContextHookTest>
        </HookContext.Provider>
    );
}

function ContextHookInfo() {
    const themeContext = React.useContext(HookContext);
    console.log("Theme:", themeContext);
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={themeContext.selectedTheme.style}>Hook theme color is {themeContext.selectedTheme.name}</p>
            <button onClick={themeContext.themeSetter()}>Change hook theme</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `onClick={themeContext.themeSetter()}` ---> `onClick={() => themeContext.themeSetter()}` or `onClick={themeContext.themeSetter}`

Comment: Because you explicitly fire it.

Comment: If you add () to the function name, you execute the function on render. Omit those () and react knows which function to call on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function `onClick={themeContext.themeSetter()}` to
`onClick={themeContext.themeSetter}`

Comment: but what if he really needed to pass a value?

Comment: Then you can do something like this
 `onClick={() => themeContext.themeSetter(some_value)}`